# How to setup Azure Application Gateway as reverse proxy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, reverse-proxy, azure-application-gateway

Is it possible to duplicate request to several Ip addresses in Azure with Application Gateway? How to do it?

Comment: Or maybe I should use Azure API Management?

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve. Your heading says "reverse proxy", but in your question you say "duplicate". please clarify your question with what you actual goal is

Comment: @silent, I work on adding new API to our existing infrastructure. But old one also should work. And I need to send 1 request to 2 API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replicate one incoming call to multiple APIs, you can use one-way-request/fire-and-forget calls in APIM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-send-request#send-one-way-request